# ASP Master pages: How to pass a value from a child page to a SqlDataSource parameter on a master page

Tags: asp.net

Here's a puzzle. A datasource on a master page refers for its SelectParameter to a label control containing some text on a (grand)child page:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ... SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblMyTable] WHERE (([strField] = ?) ">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter Name="strField" ControlID="cphMaster$cphChild$lblGrandchild" propertyname="Text" DbType="String"/>
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

but this generates an error ("System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.")

I've checked the obvious (strField really is a string, the ContentPlaceHolder (cph) controls are correctly identified by their IDs).  Any ideas?

And is my basic approach of 'ControlParameter reading a control placed in a ContentPlaceholder(s)' a reasonable way of passing a value into a SelectParameter?

Comment: I am sure what you are wanting to do can be done. But I think that there might be something wrong with your design. Why are you doing something that appears specific to a particular page in your master page? If it doesn't apply to all pages then it shouldn't be in your master page. If there is some functionality that you are wanting then you should extend the Page class with your own and then use that for your other pages. You can then still have a master page for your layout, look and feel.

Comment: @uriDium You're right to query this, but in fact I do have a genuine need for this type of solution: around 40 different landing pages each using the results (in a common listview design) from different criteria (along with each page's individual elements - headings, text, images, etc) plus many common elements (banner, footer, etc and the listview) expressed in the nested master pages.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to create a public property with type SQLDataSource on your master page class that can be accessed to your child page.

**YourMasterPage.vb (class name of master page is YourMasterPage)**

```
Private _mastersqldatasource as SqlDataSource
Public ReadOnly Property MasterSQLDataSource() As SqlDataSource
        Get
            Return SqlDataSource1
        End Get
End Property
```

Then you can access it to your child page

```
dim myMasterPage as YourMasterPage
myMasterPage = DirectCast(Me.Page.Master, YourMasterPage)
myMasterPage.MasterSQLDataSource.SelectParameters("strField").DefaultValue = lblGrandChild.Text
```

Hope this helps, I used to use this way for your case

Comment: Thanks and kudos for your solution, which looks effective. I guess yours is the more usual approach. Mine has less code though and in my circs might arguably be a little easier to deploy/maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code in your child page .cs file .

```
SqlDataSource ds = this.MasterPage.FindControl("datasourceid");
// now you can custimize this ds according to your problem
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my method is fine. In my real application I had several criteria, and the problem was that the SelectParameters were not in the same order as the criteria in the WHERE clause. When the order is the same, the method works.

So:

```
SELECT * FROM [myTable] WHERE [FieldA] = ? AND [FieldB] = ? AND [FieldC] = ?
```

needs:

```
   <SelectParameters>
      <asp:ControlParameter Name="FieldA" ControlID="cphMaster$cphChild$lblGrandChildA .../>
      <asp:ControlParameter Name="FieldB" ControlID="cphMaster$cphChild$lblGrandChildB .../>
      <asp:ControlParameter Name="FieldC" ControlID="cphMaster$cphChild$lblGrandChildC .../>
   </SelectParameters>
```

ie, not ACB, etc.  I've never before come across this behaviour, which may arise from the master/child(/grandchild) structure. Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Congratulation it seems you able to fix the issue. If you allow your users to use some various browsers (e.g: IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari).
You might need to check whether **`cphMaster$cphChild$lblGrandChildA`** is the same generate ID for your control, in some browser it will rendered as **`cphMaster_cphChild_lblGrandChildA`** with **underscore**, but if you only allow your user to use only one browser, then it will not be an issue.